# How to count the number of times a certain SSN number is occuring in a particular cell in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, regex, dataframe

I have a dataframe column with random unstructured entries. I need to count the number of times the SSN numbers are appearing in a particular cell.
Consider the below example as entries in a dataframe column:

the SSN 569-458-555 has to be replaced by 8965-78-698

SSN:25-965-9654 has to be coverage of$59 and 8968-65965 of $85

please find SSN#256-8695-65

payment completed for SSN= 569856-548, 55866-89-96,56478-9658

Output:

2

2

1

3

Answer (score 0):

Text used as input

```
Text
the SSN 569-458-555 has to be replaced by 8965-78-698
SSN:25-965-9654 has to be coverage of$59 and 8968-65965 of $85
please find SSN#256-8695-65
payment completed for SSN= 569856-548, 55866-89-96,56478-9658
```

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep="\n")
print(df)

# convert to nine-digit number in the format "AAA-GG-SSSS"
def format_ssn(x):
    ssn_l = []
    for ssn in x:
        res = re.split(r"(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{4})", ssn)
        # res[1:-1] clear empty matches from begin/end of string
        ssn_l.append("-".join(res[1:-1]))
    return ssn_l

dft = df["Text"].str.replace("-", "")
df["Count"] = dft.str.count(pat="(\d{9})")

df["SSNs"] = dft.str.findall(pat=r"(\d{9})")
df["SSNs"] = df["SSNs"].apply(lambda x: format_ssn(x))

print(df)
```

Output from *df*

```
                                         Text  Count                                     SSNs
0  the SSN 569-458-555 has to be replaced ...      2               [569-45-8555, 896-57-8698]
1  SSN:25-965-9654 has to be coverage of$5...      2               [259-65-9654, 896-86-5965]
2                        please find SSN#2...      1                            [256-86-9565]
3  payment completed for SSN= 569856-548, ...      3  [569-85-6548, 558-66-8996, 564-78-9658]
```